# SO Metabadges proposal (not: badges on meta)

Tags: discussion, badges

If you're a cynic if it comes to badges and reputation then you probably don't care about this. But bear in mind that some people find the achievement system fun, regardless of the fact that the main purpose is to add useful content.

As SE main idea on keeping people motivated to be active is *gamification*, it should affect as much space on users reputation-line as possible. It seems that after certain amount of time long-time users with huge reputation score and all possible badges earned many times loose also some fun related with the *achievement process*.

So this is a proposition to add another level of abstraction to the badge system: metabadges, which is intended to prolong, at least by a bit, the *gamification* effect for users who are close to "achieving everything".

Let's add the following bronze badges:

- [image] for 50 (?) gold badges
- [image] for 50 (?) silver badges
- [image] for 50 (?) bronze badges

silver badges:

- [image] for 100 (?) gold badges
- [image] for 100 (?) silver badges
- [image] for 100 (?) bronze badges

gold badges:

- [image] for 200 (?) gold badges
- [image] for 200 (?) silver badges
- [image] for 200 (?) bronze badges

Particular badge numbers should probably be scaled more adequately to reflect hardness of gathering badges of particular type.

The *metabadge* indicates a badge collecting achievement, thus for example *gold metabadge* denotes an achievement of collecting a particular amount of gold badges. Although it's a *gold* metabadge, it can be gold, silver or bronze depending on the number of collected gold badges. I find this level-metalevel mixup amusing, however the names could also be changed to be less confusing (i.e. "badge collector" or something similar).

If this turns out to be worth anything we can add [badge-request](/questions/tagged/badge-request) to this question, for now I'll put only the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag.

Comment: You've got a bit too meta for me

Comment: @Oded I considered adding description of possible further development into n-th order metabadges, but withdrawn this idea for now ;)

Comment: Holy hell, 200 gold badges? Yea, those numbers need tweaking. As far as I can see, there's only one person on SO that has that, and we can all guess who.

Comment: We already have badge counts that serve this purpose.  Looking at the top bar and seeing that I have 209 silver badges is already more informative than seeing that I have a gold silver metabadge, since I don't have to look up what "209 silver" means.

Comment: So the idea of this is to incentivize the collection of badges, which are meant to incentivize positive behavior. Which means this is pointless, right? You're trying to make me want to do something I'm already meant to want to do.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName Yeah, didn't have time to find particular badge statistics. I'll look into it, or if you want - feel free to edit them.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Still the raw number isn't as fun, as another, more elite, type of badge. I agree that in terms of being strictly pragmatic this doesn't add much. But it's fun. IMHO ;)

Comment: ^ also @benisuǝqbackwards

Comment: *It seems that after certain amount of time long-time users with huge reputation score and all possible badges earned many times loose also some fun related with the achievement process.*. **Nope, not feeling it.** */me goes back to pushing for the 250 silver badges line. So close!*

Comment: So what are we to do when you have earned all the gold meta badges? Introduce meta meta badges?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, I thought about it also ;) ([second comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211491/so-metabadges-proposal-not-badges-on-meta#comment679897_211491)).

Comment: I think this is an **awesome** idea.  Awesomely horrible, that is.  So I'm gonna shoot for a Silver Gold Metabadge and a Gold Bronze Metabadge?!?  If I want achievements that badly, I'll buy a bargain bin Xbox game.

Comment: What badge do we give to reward badges? meta-badges And what badge do we give to reward meta-badges? meta-meta badges and after that? meta-meta-meta badges. And after that? Good god man it's meta badges all the way down!

Comment: @JohnnyBones Shhhh! Don't give away my secrets!

Comment: This is pretty clearly a feature request, rather than just a discussion.

Comment: Badges should have actual names, like Captain, Emperor, and Master of the Universe.

Comment: All gold megabadges should be about as difficult as each other. The Gold gold megabadge would be much harder than the gold bronze megabadge

Comment: @RichardTingle megabadge != metabadge

Comment: "*Badges should have actual names, like Captain, Emperor, and **Jon Skeet**. – The Grinch*" Fixed that for you.

Comment: @Servy I may have rebelled against such a confusing name

Comment: Once you have enough badges/reputation, it's just numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The current badge system exists to encourage people to adopt good behavior on SE:

- Vote
- Provide great questions and answers
- Improve the current questions and answers

Not only the meta-badges you propose is redundant with already exists on SE, but it would also move the focus a bit away from the main goal of SE, which is to provide a Q&A center, and to provide the best information possible. An existing reward system is in place to recognize the level of contribution, and the quality of those contributions. And this system is the combination of your repuation score and the amount of badges you have gained. Rewarding users for being rewarded

The meta-badges idea you propose sounds to me as if the focus of this website would be shifted slightly towards obtaining badges, rather than simply providing great questions and answers. While this wouldn't be a *bad* thing per se (after all, badges are obtained after having accomplished good deeds), this does not go towards the main goal of SE.

Plus, 200 goal badges is a jonskeetean task.

Comment: 1) Well, as you noted yourself, metabadges encourage good behaviour transitively.  2) I get your point, but I think that the direction towards which the focus is shifted is rather relative to a person, not that much dependent on whether the site has 83 badges or 86. 3) Yes, the badge counts are purely exemplary, they're irrelevant to the idea.